# foo[E1,E2,...]* glob matches desired contents, but foo[E1,E2,...]_* does not?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, glob

I saw something weird today in the behaviour of the Bash Shell when globbing.

So I ran an ls command with the following Glob:

```
ls GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_r[E1,E2,F,G1,G2,H]* | grep ":"
```

the result was as expected

```
GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_rE1_TagDirectory:
GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_rE2_TagDirectory:
GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_rF_TagDirectory:
GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_rG1_TagDirectory:
GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_rG2_TagDirectory:
GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_rH_TagDirectory:
```

however when I change the same regex by introducing an underscore to this

```
ls GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_r[E1,E2,F,G1,G2,H]_* | grep ":"
```

my expected result is the complete set as shown above, however what I get is a subset:

```
GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_rF_TagDirectory:
GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_rH_TagDirectory:
```

Can someone explain what's wrong in my logic when I introduce an underscore sign before the asterisk?

I am using Bash.

Comment: As an aside -- `ls | grep` is an antipattern that should never be used in production code. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Thanks! This page was very informative!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstand what your glob is doing.

You were expecting this:

```
GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_r[E1,E2,F,G1,G2,H]*
```

to be a glob of files that have any of those comma-separated segments but that's not what `[]` globbing does. `[]` globbing is a character class expansion.

Compare:

```
$ echo GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_r[E1,E2,F,G1,G2,H]
GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_r[E1,E2,F,G1,G2,H]
```

to what you were trying to get (which is brace `{}` expansion):

```
$ echo GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_r{E1,E2,F,G1,G2,H}
GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_rE1 GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_rE2 GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_rF GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_rG1 GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_rG2 GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_rH
```

You wanted that latter expansion.

Your expansion uses a *character class* which matches the character `E-H`, `1-2`, and `,`; it's identical to:

```
GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_r[EFGH12,]_*
```

which, as I expect you can now see, isn't going to match any two character entries (where the underscore-less version will).

Answer (score 0):

`*` in fileystem globs is not like `*` in regex.  In a regex `*` means "0 or more of the preceeding pattern," but in filesystem globs it means "anything at all of any size".  So in your first example, the `_` is just part of the "anything" from the `*` but in the second you're matching any single character within your character class (not the patterns you seem to be trying to define) followed by `_` followed by anything at all.

Also, character classes don't work the way you're trying to use them.  `[...]` will match any character within the brackets, so your pattern is actually the same as `[EFGH12,]` since those are all the letters in class you define.

To get the grouping of patterns you want, you should use `{` instead of `[` like

```
ls GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_r{E1,E2,F,G1,G2,H}_* | grep ":"
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, and [this article](http://www.linfo.org/wildcard.html) supports my me, the square brackets don't work as a choice but as a character set, so using `[E1,E2,F,G1,G2,H]` actually is equivalent to exactly one occurrence of `[EGHF12,]`. You can then interpret the second result as "one character of `EGHF12,` and an underscore", which matches `GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_rF_TagDirectory:` but not `GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_rG1_TagDirectory:` (there is the `r` followed by more that "one occurrence of...").

The first regex works because you used the asterisk, which matches what is missed by the wrong `[...]`.

A correct expression would be:

```
ls GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_r{E1|E2|F|G1|G2|H}* | grep ":"
```

Comment: Correct explanation of the problem but that's not a correct shell expansion for what he wants. Shell globs are not regular expressions.

Comment: I know regex are not shell globs, can you please explain what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: Run `echo GM12878_Hs_InSitu_MboI_r{E1|E2|F|G1|G2|H}`. What do you get/see?